# Prove that if $\{s_n\}$ diverges to infinity then $\{-s_n\}$ diverges to minus infinity

Tags: real-analysis

I don't know how to bridge or form a connection between the two sets.

Comment: Try writing out what it means to diverge to infinity, and then applying what you know about the second sequence. Also, please put your question in the body.

Comment: Please take note that $\{s_n\}$ refers to a sequence and not to the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M<0$. Then $-M>0$. Since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=\infty,$$ there exists $N\in\Bbb N$ such that for all $n\geq N$ we have $s_n>-M$, that is, $-s_n<M$. This shows that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(-s_n)=-\infty.$$